# NIFI: how to update config data from custom processor

Tags: java, apache-nifi

in my custom processor i need to update config file(it is placed in one of nifi folder, it is  not original config ) based on data which i get from upstream connection but i can't get  desired result what should i do?

1. is  there any  way   i can controll  upstream connection flowfile 
   destination i mean  when  i  make  debugging i use  this  function     fileQueue.drainTo(file, batchSize) in this  part "file "  was  null
2. here is  one more  thing  i am interested in, on this   line 
   session.commit()  i always  get  errors that :**"trnasfer operation isn't  specified"** and  tanks  to it   whole  operation is  failed ?
3. it seems  that  when i  try  to make  session.exportTo() operations  it  doesnt   write  anything in dotCopyFile,  how  should  i  fix it?
4. should  i clean  fileQueue and  then  make session.commit()?

   FlowFile flowfile;
       @Override
       public void onTrigger(ProcessContext context, ProcessSession session) throws ProcessException {
           final String conflictResponse = context.getProperty(CONFLICT_RESOLUTION).getValue();
           final ArrayList value = new ArrayList<>();

   ```
       flowfile = session.get();
       if (flowfile == null) {
         return;
       }
       value.add(flowfile.getAttribute("filename"));
       session.remove(flowfile);


       final File directory = new File(context.getProperty(DIRECTORY).evaluateAttributeExpressions().getValue());


       final boolean keepingSourceFile = context.getProperty(KEEP_SOURCE_FILE).asBoolean();
       final ComponentLog logger = getLogger();


       if (fileQueue.size() < 100) {
           final long pollingMillis = context.getProperty(POLLING_INTERVAL).asTimePeriod(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
           if ((queueLastUpdated.get() < System.currentTimeMillis() - pollingMillis) && listingLock.tryLock()) {
               try {
                   final Set<File> listing = performListing(directory, fileFilterRef.get(), context.getProperty(RECURSE).asBoolean().booleanValue());


                   queueLock.lock();
                   try {
                       listing.removeAll(inProcess);
                       if (!keepingSourceFile) {
                           listing.removeAll(recentlyProcessed);
                       }


                       fileQueue.clear();
                       fileQueue.addAll(listing);


                       queueLastUpdated.set(System.currentTimeMillis());
                       recentlyProcessed.clear();


                       if (listing.isEmpty()) {
                           context.yield();
                       }
                   } finally {
                       queueLock.unlock();
                   }
               } finally {
                   listingLock.unlock();
               }
           }
       }


       final int batchSize = context.getProperty(BATCH_SIZE).asInteger();
       final List<File> file = new ArrayList<>(batchSize);


       queueLock.lock();
       try {
           fileQueue.drainTo(file, batchSize);
           if (file.isEmpty()) {
               return;
           } else {
               inProcess.addAll(file);
           }
       } finally {
           queueLock.unlock();
       }


       //make  xml parsing
       DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();




       try {
           dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
       } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }


       try {
           File f = file.get(0);
           doc = dBuilder.parse(f);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("localAttributes");
       for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {


           Node nNode = nList.item(temp);




           if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {


               Element eElement = (Element) nNode;




               start = eElement.getElementsByTagName("start").item(0).getTextContent();
               startDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("startDate").item(0).getTextContent();
               endDate = eElement.getElementsByTagName("endDate").item(0).getTextContent();
               patch = eElement.getElementsByTagName("patch").item(0).getTextContent();
               runAs = eElement.getElementsByTagName("runAs").item(0).getTextContent();
               makeVersion = eElement.getElementsByTagName("makeVersion").item(0).getTextContent();
               ///parameter = eElement.getElementsByTagName("parameter").item(0).getTextContent();




           }
       }
       final ListIterator<File> itr = file.listIterator();
       FlowFile flowFile1 = null;
       try {
           final Path directoryPath = directory.toPath();
           while (itr.hasNext()) {
               final File files = itr.next();
               final Path filePath = files.toPath();
               final Path relativePath = directoryPath.relativize(filePath.getParent());
               String relativePathString = relativePath.toString() + "/";
               if (relativePathString.isEmpty()) {
                   relativePathString = "./";
               }
               final Path absPath = filePath.toAbsolutePath();
               final String absPathString = absPath.getParent().toString() + "/";


               flowFile1 = session.create();
               final long importStart = System.nanoTime();
               flowFile1 = session.importFrom(filePath, keepingSourceFile, flowFile1);
               final long importNanos = System.nanoTime() - importStart;
               final long importMillis = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.convert(importNanos, TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS);


               flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key(), files.getName());
               flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, CoreAttributes.PATH.key(), relativePathString);
               flowFile1 = session.putAttribute(flowFile1, CoreAttributes.ABSOLUTE_PATH.key(), absPathString);
               Map<String, String> attributes = getAttributesFromFile(filePath);
               if (attributes.size() > 0) {
                   flowFile1 = session.putAllAttributes(flowFile1, attributes);
               }


               InputStream ffStream = session.read(flowFile1);
               DocumentBuilderFactory builderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
               DocumentBuilder builder = builderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
               Document xmlDocument = builder.parse(ffStream);


               XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
               XPathExpression myNodeList = (XPathExpression) xPath.compile("/localAttributes");
               Node nodeGettingChanged = (Node) myNodeList.evaluate(xmlDocument, XPathConstants.NODE);
               NodeList childNodes = nodeGettingChanged.getChildNodes();
               boolean  make=false;
               for (int i = 0; i != childNodes.getLength(); ++i) {
                   Node child = childNodes.item(i);
                   if (!(child instanceof Element))
                       continue;
                   if(child.getNodeName().equals("start")){
                       String date;
                       for(int  j=0;j<value.size();j++) {
                           if(value.get(j).length()>10){
                               date=value.get(j).substring(0,10);
                           }
                           else{
                               date=value.get(j);
                           }
                           if (date == child.getFirstChild().getTextContent()){
                               child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue(addOneDay(child.getFirstChild().getTextContent()));
                               make=true;


                           }
                       }
                   }
                   if(make){
                       if(child.getNodeName().equals("runAs")){
                           child.getFirstChild().setNodeValue("true");
                       }
                   }






               }
               TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
               Transformer transformer = null;
               transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
               DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
               String path = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/nifi-1.3.0/nifi-assembly/target/nifi-1.3.0-bin/nifi-1.3.0/1/conf.xml";
               File f = new File(path);
               StreamResult file1 = new StreamResult(f);
               try {
                   transformer.transform(source, file1);
               } catch (TransformerException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }




               session.write(flowFile1, new StreamCallback() {
                   @Override
                   public void process(InputStream inputStream, OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
                       TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                       Transformer transformer = null;
                       try {
                           transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                       } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       DOMSource source = new DOMSource(xmlDocument);
                       ffStream.close();
                       ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                       StreamResult result = new StreamResult(bos);




                       try {
                           transformer.transform(source, result);
                       } catch (TransformerException e) {
                           e.printStackTrace();
                       }
                       byte[] array = bos.toByteArray();
                       outputStream.write(array);
                   }


               });


               Path tempDotCopyFile = null;
               try {
                   final Path rootDirPath = Paths.get("C://Users//user//Desktop//try2//nifi-1.3.0//1");
                   final Path tempCopyFile = rootDirPath.resolve("." + flowFile1.getAttribute(CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key()));
                   final Path copyFile = rootDirPath.resolve(flowFile1.getAttribute(CoreAttributes.FILENAME.key()));


                   if (!Files.exists(rootDirPath)) {
                       if (context.getProperty(CREATE_DIRS).asBoolean()) {
                           Files.createDirectories(rootDirPath);
                       } else {
                           flowFile1 = session.penalize(flowFile1);
                           session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_FAILURE);
                           logger.error("Penalizing {} and routing to 'failure' because the output directory {} does not exist and Processor is "
                                   + "configured not to create missing directories", new Object[]{flowFile1, rootDirPath});
                           return;
                       }
                   }


                   final Path dotCopyFile = tempCopyFile;
                   tempDotCopyFile = dotCopyFile;
                   Path finalCopyFile = copyFile;


                   final Path finalCopyFileDir = finalCopyFile.getParent();
                   if (Files.exists(finalCopyFileDir)) { // check if too many files already
                       final int numFiles = finalCopyFileDir.toFile().list().length;


                       if (numFiles >= 34) {
                           flowFile1 = session.penalize(flowFile1);
                           logger.warn("Penalizing {} and routing to 'failure' because the output directory {} has {} files, which exceeds the "
                                   + "configured maximum number of files", new Object[]{flowFile1, finalCopyFileDir, numFiles});
                           session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_FAILURE);
                           return;
                       }
                   }


                   if (Files.exists(finalCopyFile)) {
                       switch (conflictResponse) {
                           case REPLACE_RESOLUTION:
                               Files.delete(finalCopyFile);
                               logger.info("Deleted {} as configured in order to replace with the contents of {}", new Object[]{finalCopyFile, flowFile1});
                               break;
                           case IGNORE_RESOLUTION:
                               session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS);
                               logger.info("Transferring {} to success because file with same name already exists", new Object[]{flowFile1});
                               return;
                           case FAIL_RESOLUTION:
                               flowFile1 = session.penalize(flowFile1);
                               logger.warn("Penalizing {} and routing to failure as configured because file with the same name already exists", new Object[]{flowFile1});
                               session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_FAILURE);
                               return;
                           default:
                               break;
                       }
                   }


                   session.exportTo(flowFile1, dotCopyFile, false);


                   final String permissions = "-rwxrwx---";
                   if (permissions != null && !permissions.trim().isEmpty()) {
                       try {
                           String perms = stringPermissions(permissions);
                           if (!perms.isEmpty()) {
                               Files.setPosixFilePermissions(dotCopyFile, PosixFilePermissions.fromString(perms));
                           }
                       } catch (Exception e) {
                           logger.warn("Could not set file permissions to {} because {}", new Object[]{permissions, e});
                       }
                   }










                   boolean renamed = false;
                   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) { // try rename up to 10 times.
                       if (dotCopyFile.toFile().renameTo(finalCopyFile.toFile())) {
                           renamed = true;
                           break;// rename was successful
                       }
                       Thread.sleep(100L);// try waiting a few ms to let whatever might cause rename failure to resolve
                   }


                   if (!renamed) {
                       if (Files.exists(dotCopyFile) && dotCopyFile.toFile().delete()) {
                           logger.debug("Deleted dot copy file {}", new Object[]{dotCopyFile});
                       }
                       throw new ProcessException("Could not rename: " + dotCopyFile);
                   } else {
                       logger.info("Produced copy of {} at location {}", new Object[]{flowFile1, finalCopyFile});
                   }


                   /*session.getProvenanceReporter().send(flowFile, finalCopyFile.toFile().toURI().toString(), stopWatch.getElapsed(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
                   session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS);*/
                   session.getProvenanceReporter().receive(flowFile1, files.toURI().toString(), importMillis);
                   //session.transfer(flowFile1, REL_SUCCESS);
                   session.remove(flowFile1);
               } catch (final Throwable t) {
                   if (tempDotCopyFile != null) {
                       try {
                           Files.deleteIfExists(tempDotCopyFile);
                       } catch (final Exception e) {
                           logger.error("Unable to remove temporary file {} due to {}", new Object[]{tempDotCopyFile, e});
                       }
                   }


                   flowFile1 = session.penalize(flowFile1);
                   logger.error("Penalizing {} and transferring to failure due to {}", new Object[]{flowFile1, t});
                   session.transfer(flowFile1,REL_FAILURE);
               }
           }








           if (!isScheduled()) {  // if processor stopped, put the rest of the files back on the queue.
               queueLock.lock();
               try {
                   while (itr.hasNext()) {
                       final File nextFile = itr.next();
                       fileQueue.add(nextFile);
                       inProcess.remove(nextFile);
                   }
               } finally {
                   queueLock.unlock();
               }
           }
       } catch (IOException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (ParserConfigurationException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (XPathExpressionException e1) {
           e1.printStackTrace();
       } catch (org.xml.sax.SAXException e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
       session.commit();
   }
   ```

Comment: it's seems you try to write a processor for things that nifi can do out of box or with small modification.  I think it's better to describe your needs and ask for suggestion how to do that with help of nifi. For example this task: `update config data` could be done with simple ExecuteScript.

Comment: Do   you mean  that  i should  reiteive file  from  folder and  make  this update   operation in ececuteScript processor  ?   if i  make  this  how can  i  send  modified   file  back  to  local  folder?

Comment: `new File(filepath).getText()` to read whole file, `new File(filepath).setText(newtext)` to write whole file

Comment: ok   this  operation  i mean   new File(filepath).getText() can  open  any  kind  of  file  i  mean  xml  for  exmaple,in  this case  should   i use   getFile->executeScript->putfile?